# write a twice function that multiplies one number four times by itself in the format below

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function called twice that takes a function f and a value x as its parameters and returns `f(f(x))`. For example,

```
twice(function (x) { return x * x; }, 3)
```

should return `81`. How do I do it?

Comment: Can you explain your question with a clear code example?

Comment: try to think about how to write a function declaration that accepts a function and another argument, then in the body applies that function to the argument and returns the result.... (hint: it's really, really short).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is stopping you? You already has the answer with you. It is working pretty fine.

```js
function twice(f, x) {
  return f(f(x));
}

var result = twice(function(n){return n*n;}, 3);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the anonymous function twice which is passed as an argument. On the second call use the returned value of first execution as the argument.

```js
function twice(funct, a) {      
  return funct(funct(a));
}


console.log(
  twice(function(x) {
    return x * x;
  }, 3)
);
```

Comment: You have understood the OP properly. +1